# Delete all lines not matching a multi-line selection

Tags: regular-expression, global-command

I'm aware that `:g/<body/ .,/body>/d` can be used to delete everything within the multi-line selection betweeh `<body` and `body>`.

I'm also aware that `:g!/<pattern>/d` can be used to delete all lines not matching the pattern.

How do I combine these 2 to delete everything except the the multi-line selection?

Comment: This will be very complex to be done in Vim. You can use the `decorare`, `sort`, `undecorate` pattern to achive this. But I doubt this is easily doable with a vim oneliner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to delegate that task to Sed. Any of these work:

```
:%!sed '/<body/,/body>/\!d'
:%!sed -n '/<body/,/body>/p'
```

Note that the exclamation mark needs to be escaped lest Vim itself does something with it. If the regex gets fairly complicated I suggest running Sed from the shell because it might be a pain escaping Vim meta-characters.

Comment: You could maybe combine `execute` with `shellescape` or similar